# Enable button when text entered in textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access form with a command button and a textbox. The button is disabled when the form starts.

I want to enable it when the user enters text and disable it when user removes text.

I want code similar to `if txt = "" then button.enabled = false else button enabled = true`. I tried that code, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775254/how-disable-a-button-if-there-is-no-text-in-multiple-textboxes-in-vb is for multiple textboxes but you will get the idea.

Comment: or https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/2043/disable-enable-buttons-in-userforms

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the `TextBox.Change` event as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.change

Something like the following should point you in the right direction:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If (TextBox1.Text = vbNullString) Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    Else
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And I personally like using `vbNullString` when checking for empty strings. You can find more about this by looking at this post: [Is there any difference between vbNullString and ""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435320/is-there-any-difference-between-vbnullstring-and)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the *AfterUpdate* event of the textbox:

```vb
Private Sub YourTextBox_AfterUpdate()

    Me!YourButton.Enabled = (Nz(Me!YourTextBox.Value) <> "")

End Sub
```